# Cannot read property 'native-element' of undefined Angular 8

Tags: angular, viewchild, angular8

after my angular application versions upgrade from **angular 7** to **angular 8**
i run into a complication problem with rows like this

```js
export class followupComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('message') messageElement: ElementRef;

    constructor(){}
    ...
}
```

I read that the new definition required `static` parameter
and change the code

```
@ViewChild('message', { static: true })) messageElement: ElementRef;
```

and I thought that the problem had resolved.

But no, i accept run time error:

> cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

related to this code

HTML:

```html
<div class="message">
    <div class="action-buttons">
        <img src="{{imgPath + '_Edit_Hover.png'}}" (click)="OnEdit(Followup)">
    </div>
    <textarea matInput #message [ngModel]="Followup.Message"></textarea>
</div>
```

TS:

```js
OnEdit(followup: Followup) {
    setTimeout(() => this.messageElement.nativeElement.focus());
}
```

What is the correct definition of `ElementRef` in angular 8,

or - How to resolve this problem?

Comment: where did you execute this line `setTimeout(() => this.myElement.nativeElement.focus());`. Please share us your full code.

Comment: Haven't started with Angular 8 yet, but elements are available after view is initialized [ AfterViewInit hook ]

Comment: Have you initialized nativeElement in constructor?

Comment: Bear Nithi, faizan and varundhariyal, I provide additional code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`<textarea matInput #message [ngModel]="Followup.Message"></textarea>` this piece of code probably needs some logic to get displayed (such as `*ngIf` or `*ngFor` on parent nodes, or some asynchronous code) which means that one changedetection cycle is required for it to get displayed.

According to [Angular 8 docs](https://v8.angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description)

> static - whether or not to resolve query results before change
> detection runs (i.e. return static results only). If this option is
> not provided, the compiler will fall back to its default behavior,
> which is to use query results to determine the timing of query
> resolution. If any query results are inside a nested view (e.g.
> *ngIf), the query will be resolved after change detection runs. Otherwise, it will be resolved before change detection runs.

so you should set `static` to `false`

`@ViewChild('message', { static: false })) messageElement: ElementRef;`

here is a simple demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgwhcv

in the demo above, input box gets displayed after 3 seconds. if you set `static:false` and click edit after input gets displayed it successfully focuses the input. but if you change `static:true` and click edit after input gets displayed, you will see error in the console.

Comment: In my case using ```static:false``` worked, thanks @ysf

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem because of creating an ElementRef type ChildView for a mat-option element like this

**Template**

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="handleMetaSignalChange();">
<mat-option #metaSignalOption *ngFor="let metaSignal of metaSignals" [value]="metaSignal">
                                {{ metaSignal.name }}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**Code**

```
 @ViewChild("metaSignalOption", { static: false }) selectedMetaSignal : ElementRef;

 handleMetaSignalChange() {
   console.log('Meta Signal Changed to ' + this.selectedMetaSignal.nativeElement.value);
 }
```

And I fixed the issue using MatOption instead of ElementRef because ElementRef works only for native DOM elements as per [official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef).

**Updated Code**

```
  @ViewChild("metaSignalOption", { static: false }) selectedMetaSignal : MatOption;

  handleMetaSignalChange() {
   // Now selectedMetaSignal is a MatOption, not a native Element
    console.log('Meta Signal Changed to ' + this.selectedMetaSignal.viewValue);
  }
```

Comment: Many thanks @MuhammadUmarFarooq that fixed my problem! I was also using ElementRef type for a component...

Comment: Can't import `MatOption`! Thanks